# How do I set a custom flag in Scrapy project?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working on a Scrapy project. I want to set a flag (project wise) to check if I'm running in QA mode or production mode. This flag must be accessible in any spider, middleware etc. 
I tried setting a custom flag in Scrapy settings file, but doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: settings should work, it is accesible from everywhere, share some code and what is exactly failing?

Comment: Found the solution. Setting a flag in Scrapy settings is the right way to go. Earlier, I was trying to print the flag value in my code using python's print statement, which didn't work. However using python's logging framework, I'm able to print the value of the flag which is being set in the Scrapy settings file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flag(any key-value pair) that needs project-wise access can be set in Scrapy project's settings.py.

settings.py is located at

> project_name/project_name/settings.py

In code (spiders, middlewares etc.), the flag can be accessed by

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
settings.get('QA', False)
```

Comment: using `scrapy.conf.settings` is deprecated, the best way to get settings from the spider is through itself, with `self.crawler.settings`